# Cypress VUE component testing, access methods from component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, cypress

I'm working on adding a test to components in cypress and I'm wondering if it is possible to access functions or data of tested component.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the components methods  this way:

```html
// if MyComponent.vue exposes a method called 'doSomething':

it('accesses the component methods', () => {
  cy.mount(MyComponent).then((comp) => {
    const { wrapper } = comp;
    wrapper.componentVM.doSomething();

    // rest of your test
  });
});
```